# Finding List of forest in the network using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I don’t know whether I can pull all the Forest in the network? I think the answer is no.

But when I am pulling the domain and its subdomains, in the current forest I am facing a weird problem:

When I logged into the B.com domain with the below code, the output is as below:

```
Dim domains As Object
Dim domain As Object
domains = Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains()
For Each domain In domains
    OutPut(domain.Name)      ‘//Output is : A.com, B.com
Next domain
```

With the above code, C.com is missing. In the below code, I get it.

```
Dim rootNt As Object
Dim domainNt As Object
'rootNt = New DirectoryEntry("WinNT:")
rootNt = GetObject("WinNT:")
For Each domainNt In rootNt
  OutPut(domain.Name)      ‘//Output is : C.com
Next domainNt
```

In the second code snippet A.com and B.com is missing.

But I want the results of both the codes. Can somebody tell me what is the difference between these codes and how I can get the result I want?